# Rotation in X axis for object OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, glut

I need help for X axis rotation of this object.
Currently if I press the mouse left/right button, then it will rotate only y axis. [1st](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGUMu.png)
[2nd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfvS8.png)
[3rd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUYEi.png)
[4th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN2pp.png) & so on... I am currently using Codeblockson Windows 10 with open source Glut packages
In which lines I have to change for X axis rotation of that cone that chanages the cones position for x axis.

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
static int slices = 16;
static int stacks = 16;
int rotation_lock=0,smotoh_color_transition_lock=0,mouse_rotation_zoom_lock=0,i;
GLuint colorCounter = 0, angle=0;
GLfloat lightXPos = 0.0f;
GLfloat lightYPos = 0.f;
static void resize(int width, int height)
{
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;  //windows size
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); //projection
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0); //near, far value
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity() ;
}
static void display(void)
{
    const double t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;  //time of camera/color change
    const double a = t*90.0;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0,0,-6); //translate
        glRotated(60,1,0,0); //rotate of angle, x,y
        if (rotation_lock==1) //If auto rotate enabled
        {
            glRotated(a,0,0,1); //then it will rotate against
        }
    //glutSolidCube(1.0);
    glutSolidCone(1,1,slices,stacks);
    //glutSolidTeapot(1.0);
    //glutSolidSphere(1.0,slices,stacks);
    //glutSolidCube(1.5);
    glPopMatrix();
    //Color for the object
    GLfloat diffColors[6][4] = {
                                {0.5, 0.5, 0.9, 1.0},
                                {0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0},
                                {0.5, 0.9, 0.3, 1.0},
                                {0.9, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0},
                                {0.3, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0},
                                {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0}
                                }; //for c
     GLfloat diffColors2[50][4] = {
                                 {0, 0, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.2, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.3, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.4, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.5, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.6, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.7, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.8, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 0.9, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0, 1, 1.0},
                                 {0.1, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.2, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.3, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.4, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.5, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.6, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.7, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.8, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.9, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {1, 0, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.2, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.3, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.4, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.5, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.6, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.7, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.8, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.9, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.1, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.2, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.3, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.4, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.5, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.6, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.7, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.8, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0.9, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {1, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.1, 0, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.2, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.3, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.4, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.5, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.6, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.7, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.8, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 0.9, 0.1, 1.0},
                                 {0, 1, 0.1, 1.0}
                                 }; //for transition
    if(smotoh_color_transition_lock==1) //If auto color transition enabled
    {
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, diffColors2[colorCounter]); //t count
    }
    else
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, diffColors[colorCounter]); // c count
    // Define specular color and shininess
    GLfloat specColor[] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    GLfloat shininess[] = {100.0};
    // Note that the specular color and shininess can stay constant
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SPECULAR, specColor);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_SHININESS, shininess);
    // Set light properties
    // Light color (RGBA)
    GLfloat Lt0diff[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0};
    // Light position
    GLfloat Lt0pos[] = {1.0f + lightXPos, 1.0f + lightYPos, 5.0f, 1.0f};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, Lt0diff);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, Lt0pos); //light position change
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
static void key(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
        case 'w': //Move up
            glTranslatef(0,0.1,0);
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 's': //Move down
            glTranslatef(0,-0.1,0);
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'd'://Move right
            glTranslatef(0.1,0,0);
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'a': //Move left
            glTranslatef(-0.1,0,0);
            glutPostRedisplay();
            break;
        case 'c': //Color toggle
            smotoh_color_transition_lock=0;
            colorCounter += 1;
            if(colorCounter>5)
                colorCounter=0;
            break;
        case 't': //Enable/Disable smooth color transition
            smotoh_color_transition_lock=1; //c enabled
            colorCounter += 1;
            if(colorCounter>49) //
                colorCounter=0;
            break;
        case 'r': //Enable/Disable auto rotation
            if(rotation_lock==0)
                rotation_lock=1; 
            else
                rotation_lock=0;
            break;
        case 'x': //Switch between rotation or zoom using mouse action
            if(mouse_rotation_zoom_lock==0)
                mouse_rotation_zoom_lock=1;
            else
                mouse_rotation_zoom_lock=0;
            break;
        case 27 : //exit when ESC is pressed
        case 'q': //exit when q is pressed
            exit(0);
            break;
      default:
            printf("Unhandled key press %c\n",key);

    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void specialFunc( int key, int x, int y )
{
    switch ( key )
    {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:  //UP key to move the light source UP
        lightYPos += 0.5f; //ligh post change
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:  //DOWN key to move the light source DOWN
        lightYPos += -0.5f;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:  //LEFT key to move the light source LEFT
        lightXPos += -0.5f;
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:  //RIGHT key to move the light source RIGHT
        lightXPos += 0.5f;
        break;
    }
    // this will refresh the screen so that the user sees the light position
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void mouse(int button, int state, int mousex, int mousey) //mouse function
{
    if (mouse_rotation_zoom_lock==1) // If zoom enabled //x chap dile
    {
        if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_UP)
        {
            glScalef(1.2,1.2,1); //zoom in
        }
        else if(button==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            glScalef(0.7,0.7,1); //zoom out
        }
    }

    else // If rotation enabled // x na chaple
    {
        if(button==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_UP)
        {
            glRotatef(25,0,0,1); //rotate
        }
        else if(button==GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state==GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            glRotatef(-25,0,0,1);
        }
    }

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

static void idle(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(250,250);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL");
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(key);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialFunc);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    //glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glutMainLoop();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Actually you're rotating around the z-Axis (`glRotatef(25,0,0,1)`) - see [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml). Rotation around x-Axis: `glRotatef(25,1,0,0)`

Comment: Sorry for the off topic question: @rafsan, is it your personal choice to use the deprecated OpenGL? If it is,then I highly recommend switching to modern OpenGL and use standard vector math to perform transformations. This way you will not have to guess how these (very old) GL methods work under the hood.